# Woocommerce sort by category

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to be able to add "Sort by Category/Department" to the sorting dropdown on the Shop page?

So we have:
Sort by Department
Sort by Newness
Sort by popularity 
Sort by price: low to high
Sort by price: high to low

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WooCommerce Products Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the help got a way around it and it's working fine... However the sorting only works for the shop page but not sub categories/pages

Any help on this?